# functions and randomization Question- beginner python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, methods, while-loop

i'm working out this problem where i have to create a game of black jack.

Question 1: My solution seems to work fine until i enter show for both player1 and player2. It just stops cold and doesn't continue onto the show_cards function in order to see who won... and i'm not sure why, the indentation is in the right place and the function is spelled the right way. why is it not continuing to execute?

Question 2: I'm using the popitem method in order to randomize my card selection when i deal cards in the deal_cards function, however every time i start the game the same cards are chosen. The Game is never a new game of black jack. How can i get it to play a new set of cards?

```
GAME = 21
def main():
    deck = create_deck()
    deal_cards(deck)   
def create_deck():
    deck = {'Ace of Spades':1,'2 of Spades':2,'3 of Spades':3,\
           '4 of Spades':4, '5 of Spades':5,'6 of Spades':6,\
           '7 of Spades':7,'8 of Spades':8, '9 of Spades':9,\
           '10 of Spades':10,'Jack of Spades':10,'Queen of Spades':10,
           'King of Spades':10,
        
           'Ace of Hearts':1,'2 of Hearts':2, '3 of Hearts':3, '4 of Hearts':4,
           '5 of Hearts':5, '6 of Hearts':6, '7 of Hearts':7,'8 of Hearts':8, 
           '9 of Hearts':9,'10 of Hearts':10, 'Jack of Hearts':10,'Queen of Hearts':10,
        
           'Ace of Clubs':1,'2 of Clubs':2, '3 of Clubs':3, '4 of Clubs':4,
           '5 of Clubs':5, '6 of Clubs':6, '7 of Clubs':7,'8 of Clubs':8, 
           '9 of Clubs':9,'10 of Clubs':10, 'Jack of Clubs':10,'Queen of Clubs':10,
        
           'Ace of Diamonds':1,'2 of Diamonds':2, '3 of Diamonds':3, '4 of Diamonds':4,
           '5 of Diamonds':5, '6 of Diamonds':6, '7 of Diamonds':7,'8 of Diamonds':8, 
           '9 of Diamonds':9,'10 of Diamonds':10, 'Jack of Diamonds':10,'Queen of Diamonds':10}
    return deck
def deal_cards(deck):
    p1hand_value = 0
    p2hand_value = 0
    print()
    print('player1:')

    for count in range(2):
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        p1hand_value+=value
    print()
    print('player2:')    

    for count in range(2):
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        p2hand_value+=value
    
    p1_another_card(deck,p1hand_value,p2hand_value)

def p1_another_card(deck,p1hand,p2hand):
    ask = input("Would you like another card player1? If yes enter 'yes' if not enter 'show'")
    ask=ask.lower()

    while ask == 'yes':
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        p1hand+=value
    
        if p1hand < GAME:
            ask = input("would you like another card? If yes enter 'yes' if not enter 'show'") 
            ask = ask.lower()
        else:
            ask = False

    p2_another_card(deck,p1hand,p2hand)         
        
def p2_another_card(deck,p1hand,p2hand):

    ask = input("Would you like another card player2? If yes enter 'yes' if not enter 'show'")
    ask=ask.lower()

    while ask == 'yes':
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        p2hand+=value
    
        if p2hand < GAME:
            ask = input("would you like another card? If yes enter 'yes' if not enter 'show'") 
            ask = ask.lower()
        else:
            ask = False

    show_cards(p1hand,p2hand)
        
def show_cards(p1hand,p2hand):

    if p1hand > GAME and p2hand < GAME:
        print('player 2 hand:',p2hand,'Winner')
        print('player 1 hand:',p1hand,"Busted")
    elif p1hand > GAME and p2hand > GAME:
        print('No one won. Both busted')
        print('player1:',p1hand)
        print('player2:',p2hand)
    elif p1hand < GAME and p2hand > GAME:
        print('player 1 hand:',p1hand,'Winner')
        print('player 2 hand:',p2hand,'Busted')
    elif p1hand < GAME and p2hand < GAME:
        diff1 = GAME-p1hand
        diff2 = GAME-p2hand
    
        if diff1 < diff2:
            print('player 1 hand:',p1hand,'winner')
        elif diff1 > diff2:
            print('player 2 hand:',p2hand,'Winner') 
    else:
        print('something went wrong')       
    
main()
```

Comment: For question 2: You could run it with let's say Python 3.5 :-P

Comment: For Q2: popitems returns pairs in LIFO order(at least v3.7 onwards): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem
First of all, a dictionary doesn't look like the best data structure to hold deck of cards. Maybe you can explore random.shuffle

Comment: The book I'm reading is teaching me with python 3.5.1 and the python I'm using with jupyter notebooks is 3.7.4

Comment: Is the book actually suggesting `popitem` for this?

Comment: I am reading starting out in python 4th edition by tony gaddis. He created a similar problem except it was just 1 player and he said to adjust his code to make it more 'simple' but he used popitem in his own example... so i just assumed that was what needed to be used. And in the book it says it returns a random key, value pair and deletes it... i didn't realize i was learning dated material...

Comment: Also, if any of you have any insights on question 1. That would be appreciated. That one is the main one that has me puzzled. Question 2 seems to just be a materials vs python environment mishap.

Comment: I wouldn't call it dated. That wasn't a proper way in 3.5, either. It was an implementation detail, or rather implementation side effect, that shouldn't have been relied on back then, either. My initial comment was only intended as a joke :-). Rather disappointed if a book like that seriously suggests it.

Comment: I copied&pasted the above code (Pycharm, venv python3.8) and it worked as intended, it shows the winner every time i tested